# unable to debug error produced while reading csv in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to csv file. Code I've written below gives error(available after code block). Not sure what I am missing or doing wrong.

```
import csv
file = open('AlfaRomeo.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)

for j in csvreader:
    print(j)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Pratik\PycharmProjects\AkraScraper\Transform_Directory\Developer_Sandbox.py", line 39, in 
> for j in csvreader:
> File "C:\Users\Pratik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 402: character maps to

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you have a character in your input file which fails the Unicode decode test. It's value is 0x8d (141 decimal), and it's the 402nd byte in the file. I suggest loading the file in a text editor and search forward until you find it. So you know what you're looking for, it's in the Extended ASCII code section of https://www.asciitable.com/.